# How could I let vim ale plugin use pylint configuration file

Tags: vim, pylint, pylintrc, vim-ale

in my `vimrc` file, I add this line:

```
let g:ale_python_pylint_options = '--rcfile ~/.pylintrc'
```

And in my `~/.pylintrc` file, I have this line:

```
msg-template={msg_id}: {msg}
```

However, with my vim ale plugin, the error message showed does not include the mssage id.

The message is like this:

```
[Pylint] Unused variable 'j' [W]
```

But I hope I could get this: 
    [Pylint] [W0612] Unused variable 'j' [W]

How could I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You could do that using the `g:ale_echo_msg_format` option. For example, setting this option in the vimrc as shown below, would give you the desired result:

```
let g:ale_echo_msg_format='[%linter%] [%severity%] %code% %s'
```

Where `code` is the error code. However, this code outputted is a human-readable code instead of the actual code. For the above an example output is as follows:

```
[pylint] [Warning] missing-docstring Missing module docstring
```

Note `missing-docstring` instead of the code `F0001`. On reading through the issues, the author of ale is [deliberately doing this](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/issues/852#issuecomment-344669312), So, if you need the actual error code, you're out of luck. Open an issue in the project and hope the author changes this behavior.

Comment: I thought maybe I could have both the readable code and the read code, but it seems that I could not have it right now from you description. Maybe I could do it in the future.